# Chart js legend are being cut off if the bar height is equal to port height - chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using chart js to display barchart as :

```
$(function(){
        let aid;
        let $radio_input;
        let none_obs;
        let display = true;
        let $js_dom_array = ["76.44", "120.00"];
        let $js_am_label_arr = ["None $0", "Terrace - Large $2000"];
        if($js_am_label_arr.length > 20){
            display = false;
        }
        let $js_backgroundColor = ["rgba(26,179,148,0.5)", "rgba(26,179,148,0.5)"];

        // let $div = document.getElementById("barChart");
        // $div.height="140";
        let ctx2 = document.getElementById("barChart").getContext("2d");
        let chart = new Chart(ctx2, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: $js_am_label_arr,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'DOM',
                    data: $js_dom_array,
                    backgroundColor: $js_backgroundColor,
                    barPercentage: 0.4,
                    maxBarThickness: 50,
                    // maxBarLength: 5,
                }]
            },
            options: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                legendCallback: function(chart) {
                    var text = [];
                    for (var i=0; i<chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
                        text.push(chart.data.labels[i]);
                    }
                    return text.join("");
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    callbacks: {
                        // Use the footer callback to display the sum of the items showing in the tooltip
                        title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                            let title_str = data['labels'][tooltipItem[0]['index']];
                            // let lastIndex = title_str.lastIndexOf(" ");
                            // return title_str.substring(0, lastIndex);
                            return title_str;
                        },
                        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                            return 'Avg. DOM: '+data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']];
                        },
                    },
                },

                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: false,
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        // scaleLabel: {
                        //     labelString: 'Month'
                        // },
                        ticks: {
                            display: display,
                            min: 0,
                            autoSkip: false,
                            maxRotation: 60,
                            callback: function(label, index, labels) {

                                // let lastIndex = label.lastIndexOf(" ");
                                // let avg_amount = label.split(" ").pop();
                                // let am_name = label.substring(0, lastIndex);
                                // let truncated_am_name = am_name.length > 30 ? (am_name.substring(0, 30)+'...') : am_name;
                                // return truncated_am_name+' '+avg_amount;
                                return label;
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                },
                layout: {
                    margin: {
                        top: 5
                    }
                },
            },
            plugins:[{
                afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart,options) {
                    // var chartInstance = chart,
                    let ctx = chart.ctx;
                    ctx.font = Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle;
                    ctx.fillStyle = Chart.defaults.global.textColor;
                    ctx.textAlign = "center";
                    ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";

                    chart.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                        var meta = chart.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                        meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                            ctx.fillText(Math.round(dataset.data[index]), bar._model.x, bar._model.y); //bar._model.y - 5
                        });
                    })
                }
            }]
        });
        document.getElementById('barChart').innerHTML = chart.generateLegend();

    })
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3"></script>

<div style="height:400px;">
    <canvas id="barChart" xheight="140px"></canvas>
</div>
```

If you need [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7eo2nz3g/2/)

Here, the value of second barchart is 120 and it is being cut off. I could pull text little down as: `ctx.fillText(Math.round(dataset.data[index]), bar._model.x, bar._model.y + 5);` But I don't wat the value to be overlapped with the bar. I have also tried with following options

```
layout: {
    margin: {
        top: 5
    }
},
```

and

```
axisY:{
    viewportMaximum: 130
},
```

But, none of these seems to work. Is there any way to increase the height or viewport of the chart js? It would be helpful if you could provide the js fiddle as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `layout.margin.top`, you need to define [`layout.padding.top`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html#padding) as follows:

```
layout: {
  padding: {
    top: 20
  }
},
```

Comment: @unminder Thank you Sir, Actually I had tried with padding as well but I had used just 5 thats may be the reason it was unnoticed.